# Nativescript with Googlemap static api - issue on iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to add an image of a map generated by the google map static api in my Nativescript application (I'm using Nativescript with Vue).
I am able to make it work on Android but I have some issues on iOS.

I simply have an Image component like that `<Image :src="map_source" />`

And in my vue data, I have map_source: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&markers=48.2,2.1&path=color:red|weight:5|fillcolor:red|48.2,2.1|48.3,2.13|48.4,2.12&zoom=10&size=460x200&key=MY_API_KEY"

When I use this URL in my browser, I get the desired map.
When I use this URL in my app on Android, it displays the map correctly.
But when I use the same URL in my app on an iOS device, the map is not displayed at all.

Note: if I remove the path (e.g map_source: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&markers=48.2,2.1&zoom=10&size=460x200&key=MY_API_KEY", the image is correctly displayed on both Android and iOS. The error only appens when I add the path.

Is this an iOS issue or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Did you try debugging the download request that happens internally on Image component Or use fetch / axios to download the image then load it from local file?

Comment: Downloading the image then loading it from a local file gets the same results

Comment: Did you see the downloaded image? Was it downloaded as expected. Because Google may return error instead of image in the request if there is something wrong. Perhaps can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I get an "Error: unsupported URL" on iOS.
Here is the Playground sample, you just have to put your api_key in the data. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=RoAFzF

Comment: Okay I got it to work, the issue was the "|" character that caused the "unsupported URL".
By using `encodeURI(url)` before calling `imageSourceModule.fromUrl(encoded_url)` I was able to display the image on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the issue thanks to @Manoj. On iOS devices, the URL was unsupported because of the "|" character. So I had to encode it like so:

```
let imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");
let url = encodeURI("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&markers=48.2,2.1&zoom=10&size=460x200&key=MY_API_KEY")
imageSourceModule.fromUrl(url).then(res => {
    this.map_source = res;
});
```